# Declaring React Routes in a separate file and Importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to React. I have been trying to declare routes in a file and then use it in another file.

Here is my routes.js

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import Template1 from './components/template1';
import Template2 from './components/template2';
import Template3 from './components/template3';

const routes = (
  <Route exact path="/" component={App}>
    <Route exact path="/sessionstate1" component={Template1} />
    <Route exact path="/sessionstate2" component={Template2} />
    <Route exact path="/sessionstate3" component={Template3} />
  </Route>
)

export default routes
```

and index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/css/index.css';
import routes from './routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am not getting any errors or warning but the page is not loading. Please tell me what I am missing

Thanks

Comment: as far as I can see, there are no accepted answers. Could you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 20):

well i had the same issue a few days ago, and the solution for me was this...

This one of the routes files:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ComponentY } from '../components/functionalitys';

export default [
  <Route path="/appointment" component={ComponentY} exact key="create" />,
];
```

This another route file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LoginPage, Register } from '../components/user';

export default [
  <Route path="/register" component={Register} exact key="create" />,
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} exact strict key="login" />
];
```

And this is how I imported in the main app.js:

```
import routesFromFile1 from './the/route';
import routesFromFile2 from './the/other/route';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
       <div className="wrapper">
           <section className="content container-fluid">
              <Switch>  
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} strict={true} exact={true}/>
                <Route path="/500" component={InternalServer} />
                {routesFromFile1}
                {routesFromFile2}
              </Switch>
            </section>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I hope this help Someone! Cheers!!

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to wrap your Routes inside a div. Try something like this:

*routes.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Template1, Template2, Template3 } from './templates';

const createRoutes = () => (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/sessionstate1" component={Template1}/>
      <Route exact path="/sessionstate2" component={Template2}/>
      <Route exact path="/sessionstate3" component={Template3}/>
    </Router>
);

export default createRoutes;
```

*index.js*

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createRoutes from './routes';

const routes = createRoutes();

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: The Router can have only one child element

Answer (score 11):

index.js:

```
import LoginRoutes from './login/routes'

let routeConfig = [];
routeConfig = routeConfig.concat(LoginRoutes(store));

<Router routes={routeConfig}/>
```

routes.js:

```
export default (store) => {

    return [
        {path: '/login', component: Login},
        {path: '/signup', component: SignUp},
    ]
}
```

This way you can add routes from different files and spread your route definitions to different folders that serve the contextual purpose of the route.

The store variable is there in case you want to use redux and want to have an onEnter event on the route. Example:

```
export default () => {

    const sessionEnter = (location) => {
        let {appId} = location.params;

        store.dispatch(loadApp(appId));

    return [
        {path: '/apps/:appId', component: App, onEnter: sessionEnter},
    ]
}
```

I find onEnter events a good alternative to componentDidMount, data-fetching-wise. Invoking a data fetch on route level makes more sense to me as I see the component as part of the presentation level.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is with wrapping the `Route` inside a `div`.
Try wrapping them inside a `Route` like following. Try this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jo1gf2pL/) and change the routes wrapper to div.

```
const routes=(
      <Route >
        <Route exact path="/sessionstate1" component={Template1}/>
        <Route exact path="/sessionstate2" component={Template2}/>
        <Route exact path="/sessionstate3" component={Template3}/>
      </Route >
)
export default routes;
```

And import it into `index.js`

```
import routes from './routes.js';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Is there an App.js or a parent class to these components

Comment: No there is no parent class

Comment: Nope. Blank page is coming

Comment: Did it work when you declare the routes inside the same index.js file.? Btw I need to see the code structure to properly help you

Comment: What is inside App.js. App.js seems like parent of the templates

Comment: App.js is not parent of templates.It is a separate component

Comment: You've wrapped the templates as children of App.js. You need to include {this.props.children} inside App.js for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

With Typescript

Sepate the file for routes as routes.ts

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/auth-callback', component: authCallback },
    { path: '/fetch-data/:startDateIndex?', component: FetchData }
];
```

In the App.tsx

```
export function App() {
    const routeComponents = routes.map(({ path, component }, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
    return (
        <Layout>
            {routeComponents}
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Layout.tsx

```
export default (props: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            <NavMenu />
            <TopAppBarFixedAdjust>
                {props.children}
            </TopAppBarFixedAdjust>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: This does not work with nested paths

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm little late but here my working
here a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/0m80zlovrl?fontsize=14)

my dependencies are

> ```
> "react": "16.2.0",
> "react-dom": "16.2.0",
> "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
> "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
> ```

create nav.js file as this 
this file is responsible for storing all the links for navbar

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Navi extends Component {
  render = () => (
    <div>
      <Link to="/">Go to Home</Link> <br />
      <Link to="/about">Go to About</Link> <br />
      <Link to="/any-route">404 page</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navi;
```

Then the routes.js file
here you will define all your routes, and your pages where the routes should navigates to

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
// your components
const Home = () => <h1>Home</h1>;
const About = () => <h1>About</h1>;
const MissingPage = () => <h1>404</h1>;

const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route component={MissingPage} />
  </Switch>
);

export default routes;
```

finally here is the code for index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import Navi from "./nav";
import routes from "./routes";

// initialize rotues and navi links
const initRoutes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Navi />
      {routes}
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const initializedRoutes = initRoutes();
ReactDOM.render(
  initializedRoutes, 
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is the routing page created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spv3k.png)

[routing page imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy7sR.png)

Hope, it will help everyone. click the link to see code.!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

#### In `react-router-dom` version 6.x.x

Suppose you have the following URLs in your react app

```
/
/home
/handlers
/handlers/notes
/handlers/users
```

you can isolate all routing components related to handlers(including its nested URLs) by:

1. Define your main routing

```
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/handlers/*" element={<AllHandlersPages />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Notice the existence of `path="/handlers/*"` where we have a wildcard `*` to tell react-router-dom to match with any nested route too

then

2. declare `AllHandlersPages` in another file like this

```
export function AllHandlersPages() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route>
        <Route index element={<HandlersIndexPage />} />
        <Route path="notes" element={<NotesPage />} />
        <Route path="users" element={<UsersPage />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

Because `<Route />` can't be defined unless it has a parent `<Routes />` don't forget to make them nested properly.

[Full working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/split-files-react-router-dom-5nte26?file=/src/pages/handlers/all-handlers.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this way

```
import React from "react";
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import NoteContainer from "./component/note/index.jsx";
import Header from "./component/common/header.jsx";

const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header/> {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};

var x = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    );
};
module.exports = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <App>
                <Route path="/" component={NoteContainer}/>
                <Route path="/inbox" component={x}/>
            </App>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

Comment: It is working when i keep it in same file but i want to declare routes separately

Answer (score 0):

I did it with very simple way. Follow the two steps below.

In `App.js`

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Header from "./component/common/header";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import routes from "./routes";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <section className="container">
        <Header />
        {routes}
      </section>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Overview from "./component/overview/overview";
import UsersList from "./component/userslist/UsersList";
import FavUserList from "./component/userslist/FavUserList";

const routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Overview} />
    <Route path="/adduser" component={UsersList} />
    <Route path="/favuser" component={FavUserList} />
  </Switch>
);

export default routes;
```

***Note: Make sure you import like this***

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

> In < Header /> component you have to declare navigation link.

Answer (score 0):

i'm starting into react too, and i figured out a way to make what you are looking for.

What i did was inside the app file (which comes default in every project) i imported the routes file, the routes file is located in a folder called approuter (you can name it whatever you want), i'll write some of my code so you can see what i mean

*//APP FILE*

```
    import AppRouter  from './router/approuter'
    
    function App() {
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className='app' id="mode">
            <AppRouter />
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }
export default App
```

*//ROUTER FILE/*

```
 import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'}
        
  import Register from "../pages/register"
  import Login from "../pages/login"

export default function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />}/>
          <Route path="register" element={<Register />}/>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This actually worked in a project i'm currently working on, i hope this can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
**index.js**

import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Paths from "./routes/Paths";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Paths />
  </React.StrictMode>
);





**Paths.js**

import LoginSample from "../portal/LoginSample";
import Dashboard from "../portal/Dashboard";

function Paths() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginSample />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default Paths;
```

Answer (score -2):

Also new to react and was running into the same issue. Here is what I tried (obviously different code and structure, but what we're looking for should be the same functionality)

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createHashHistory } from "history";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import routes from "./routes";

const allRoutes = routes;

ReactDOM.render(
  allRoutes,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

and  the routes.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import { createHashHistory } from "history";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from "./pages/App";
import Detail from "./pages/Detail";
import List from "./pages/List";

const routes =  (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ App } />
        <Route path="/" component={ List } />
        <Route path="/detail/:repo" component={ Detail } />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default routes;
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: this just moves the problen to routes.js