# How to use react useRef in a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-hooks

Am trying to use context to allow authentication state to be available to all components. However am stumped at this error

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

````
src/utils/hooks.js:22
  19 | // }, [pokemonName, run])
  20 | const defaultInitialState = { status: "idle", data: null, error: null };
  21 | function useAsync(initialState) {
> 22 |   const initialStateRef = useRef({
  23 |     ...defaultInitialState,
  24 |     ...initialState
  25 |   });```

    UseProvideAuth
src/components/helper/context.js:28
  25 | 
  26 | 
  27 | function UseProvideAuth(props) {
> 28 |   const {
  29 |     data: user,
  30 |     status,
  31 |     error,

    handleSubmit
src/components/login/login-form/index.js:13
  10 | function handleSubmit(event) {
  11 |   event.preventDefault();
  12 |   const { email, password } = event.target.elements;
> 13 |   run(
     | ^  14 |     onSubmit({
  15 |       email: email.value,
  16 |       password: password.value

Index.js

  <React.StrictMode>
    <ProvideAuth>
        <App />
    </ProvideAuth>
  </React.StrictMode>,

ProvideAuth

function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <authContext.Provider value={UseProvideAuth}>{children}</authContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

UseProvideAuth

    function UseProvideAuth(props) {
  const {
    data: user,
    status,
    error,
    isLoading,
    isIdle,
    isError,
    isSuccess,
    run,
    setData
  } = useAsync();


useAsync

const defaultInitialState = { status: "idle", data: null, error: null };
function useAsync(initialState) {
  const initialStateRef = useRef({
    ...defaultInitialState,
    ...initialState
  });

Here is a minimal setup on [codesandbox][1] 
Any help would be appreciated.


  [1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-silence-b0c8i
````

Comment: Please setup a minimal reproducible example [here](https://codesandbox.io/dashboard/home?workspace=6e40603e-c304-4744-b76d-12456eaaa21d).

Comment: Your question has an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026690/declaring-react-routes-in-a-separate-file-and-importing/46659102

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, here is a minimal setup https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-silence-b0c8i

Comment: Ref's point to a specific DOM element. They can only be used within a react component and are assigned to a DOM element before using them. They can't be set to true or false.

Comment: There is the concept of custom hook which is defined in the official docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) that am trying to follow. This should allow me use hooks in functions. And to the point of useRef pointing to DOM elements before using them, I did not get that view from the documents https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref. That just happens to be a common use case