# How to have a one whole file as a router file in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026690/declaring-react-routes-in-a-separate-file-and-importing?fbclid=IwAR3F5r40vSjDWSP8L0GYtAvHRct5kxbYZajRdCHiZ8_MGL6X0wfurbcrzEs) and I had an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.
```

I'm new to react and what I'm trying to do is making a universal router for all of my components. Is it a good idea to have all routes on a single file or have it on every file that needed it? Here are my code

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createRoutes from './routes';
const Routes = createRoutes();
ReactDOM.render(Routes,document.getElementById('root'))
```

routes.js:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from "react-router-dom";
// import {Home, Settings} from './routes/index'
import Home from './routes/Home'
import Settings from './routes/settings'
const createRoutes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
       <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
    </Router>
);

export default createRoutes
```

Edit: Here are my Home.js and Settings.Js Files:
Home.js:

```
import '../styles/home.scss'
import Cards from '../components/swiper'
import Slideshow from '../components/slideshow'
const home = ()=>{
    let user  = "user"
    return(
        <>
            <Slideshow/>
            <h1 className="welcome"> Welcome {user},</h1>
            <div className="flex Create-Event">
            <h2 className="title-headers">Featured events:</h2> 
            <a href="#" className="Btn-Primary ">Create Event</a>
            </div>
            <Cards/>
            <h2 className="title-headers">Upcoming events:</h2>
            <Cards/>
            <div className="help flex">
                <h2>Need assistance? </h2>
                <a href="" className="Btn-Primary contact" id="contact">Contact Us!</a>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default home
```

settings.js:

```
//todo : immport form and other types of settings related components here later on
function Settings() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Settings goes here</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Settings
```

Comment: Try using regular function instead of arrow function in your component located in routes.js file.

Comment: Hello, the error is still the same when I edited the createroutes and turn it in to a function, same with class.

Comment: Insert your Home and Setting component's file.

Comment: It's still the same error.

Comment: I want to see your components! nothing should be changed!

Comment: check for react-router-dom structure, think you miss Switch or Routes component

Comment: i added the home.js and Settings.js files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a hook, use a regular function.

**EDIT:** Try this. Also, I just noticed you're using *home* hook, when you're calling **Home** in Router.

index.js

```
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import createRoutes from './routes';
import MyRouter from "./MyRouter";

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyRouter />,
    document.getElementById('root'))
```

MyRouter.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
// import {Home, Settings} from './routes/index'
import Home from './routes/Home'
import Settings from './routes/settings'
function MyRouter() (
    <Router>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={<Home />}/> 
            <Route exact path="/home" component={<Home />}/>
            <Route exact path="/settings" component={<Settings />}/>
        </Routes>
    </Router>
);

export default MyRouter
```

Home.js

```
import '../styles/home.scss'
import Cards from '../components/swiper'
import Slideshow from '../components/slideshow'

function Home() {
    let user  = "user"
    return(
        <>
            <Slideshow/>
            <h1 className="welcome"> Welcome {user},</h1>
            <div className="flex Create-Event">
            <h2 className="title-headers">Featured events:</h2> 
            <a href="#" className="Btn-Primary ">Create Event</a>
            </div>
            <Cards/>
            <h2 className="title-headers">Upcoming events:</h2>
            <Cards/>
            <div className="help flex">
                <h2>Need assistance? </h2>
                <a href="" className="Btn-Primary contact" id="contact">Contact Us!</a>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Home
```

settings.js

```
function Settings() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Settings goes here</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Settings
```

Comment: is MyRouter supposed to have ```( )```  instead of  ```{ }```  ? I tried both and none of them worked.

Comment: When using `const variable = () => {}`, you are creating a hook. I'm not sure but I think Routers are required to use functions/classes and not hooks.

Comment: I've changed all to functions   and it still didn't work

Comment: Check new update

Comment: It now works! I cahnged everything into a function and I also changed the  ```components ``` with ```elements``` and it  works  the way I want it to work. Thanks !

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thank you